# Prevent app from opening after executed shortcut

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I’ve created a simple shortcut which adds clipboard to a note:
[image]

The problem is that after the shortcut has completed, the note gets open in the app afterwards. Is there a way to prevent that so the app stays in the background?

Answer (score 1):

This is up to the app developer to implement. Some apps add an option to choose whether to open the app with the result. You should contact the developer to ask if this can be added to that shortcut action.